# Where should the 'not' be placed in the sentence?

Tags: grammar, american-english, word-usage

Consider the following two:

> To whom is the cruelty of Hitler **not** known?
>
> To whom is **not** the cruelty of Hitler known?

Which one is correct? The second sentence seems very odd to me, and I can guarantee that if others use similar sentence to this, I would be unable to understand the meaning or have to struggle with that. But I want to know the opinion of a native.

And what about the following, contracted, sentence:

> To whom **isn't** the cruelty of Hitler known?

And what does that form represent - *is...not* or *is not?*

Thanks

Comment: Why load so much syntax onto a rhetorical question? It's sposta be short and snappy and make the audience think. This sentence makes the audience load the interpreter and the debugger and they don't leave any room for thinking. Try _Who is unaware of Hitler's cruelty?_ because that's what you're asking; the passive, the floating negation, the pied-piping, are all just distractions.

Answer (score 1):

The adverb "not" can often be placed a variety of places in a sentence without changing the meaning and have it remaing grammatical and natural.  In your sentence, you can say:

- To whom is *not* the cruelty of Hitler known?
- To whom is the cruelty of Hitler *not* known?
- To whom is the cruelty of Hitler known *not*?

All of the above mean the same thing and are perfectly acceptable.

Regarding the use of a contraction in the following:

- To whom *isn't* the cruelty of Hitler known?

The use of "isn't" is perfectly grammatical and acceptable in the above sentence.  However, when writing formally, like for a college paper, using contractions is generally frowned upon as being too informal.  In a doctoral thesis, for example, you won't see contractions.  You also won't see them in formal letters.  If you are to adhere to a style guide for this writing, you should consult that guide to find out what it prescribes in regards to contractions before deciding to use them.

Comment: To me, *"known not"* sounds old-fashioned and pretentious. I wouldn't recommend using it.

Comment: I would say it was perfectly acceptable ... _not_.

Comment: You can say “To whom is not …” ? Really? Well you won’t be thrown in jail for saying it, but I think you should be.

Comment: @David - Yes, really.  If you are going to throw people in jail for saying it, then you will need to throw millions in jail, even have to back in time for hundreds of years to gather up the guilty, like Oxford scholars John Wycliffe, Rev. Josiah Forshall, and Sir Frederic Madden, who in 1850 translated Isaiah 52:15 from the Latin Vulgate as "...for whom is not told of him shall see, and that not heard, be beheld."

Comment: "To whom is not known the cruelty of Hitler?" is exactly the same as saying "To whom isn't the cruelty of Hitler known?"  "Isn't" is merely a contraction of "is not."

Comment: @BenjaminHarman — Methinks thou doth protest too much.